# Need to download a file using fput() in php

Tags: php

I have multiple condition so I am trying to generate a function to download the sql data to Csv File. I am having trouble in downloading the file. Whenever I try to, the page just reloads and file doesnot download. I am not sure what I am doing wrong as when I use echo command, I can see the data displayed on page. Kindly if someone can help and direct me to right way, that would be really helpful.

```
if(isset($_POST['report'])){
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT rating_postid,rating_posttitle,COUNT(rating_rating) AS Count,AVG(rating_rating) as Average FROM wp_ratings WHERE 1=1
    GROUP BY rating_postid,rating_posttitle") or die(mysql_error());
    generate_csv($sql);
}

function generate_csv($sql){ 

    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false);
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if($num_rows >= 1)
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
            $fp = fopen('php://output','w');
            $sep = "";
            $comma= "";

    foreach($row as $name => $value)
    {
    $sep .= $comma . '' .STR_REPLACE('','""',$name);
    $comma = ",";
    }
    $sep .= "\n";

    fputs($fp,$sep);

    mysql_data_seek($sql,0);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
    $sep = "";
    $comma= "";

    foreach($row as $name => $value)
    {
    $sep .= $comma . '' .STR_REPLACE('','""',$value);
    $comma = ",";
    }
    $sep .= "\n";
    fputs($fp,$sep);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    //echo $fp; 
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'NO RECORDS IN DATABASE';
    }

}
```

Comment: Apart from your problem; Please stop using the ``mysql_*`` functions. They are deprecated for quite a while now and will stop working in PHP7. Use PDO or the ``mysqli_*`` functions.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I appreciate that !